# Mysql Join 3 tables and output all record in first table regardless another 2 table record is null

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables which is employee,quota and leave.
I want my query to show all records in employee table.
3 tables primary key as ID

```
employee
----------------
emp ID|name
----------------
1     |emp 1
2     |emp 2
3     |emp 3
4     |emp 4
----------------

quota
-----------------------
emp ID|leave type|quota
-----------------------
1     |annual    |5
1     |sick      |14
2     |annual    |4
2     |sick      |14
3     |annual    |3
3     |sick      |14
4     |annual    |2
4     |sick      |14
----------------------

leave
---------------------------------
emp ID|leave type  |date     |day
---------------------------------
1     |annual      |22-5-2013|0.5
2     |sick        |22-5-2013|1.0
1     |sick        |24-5-2013|1.0
1     |sick        |25-5-2013|1.0
---------------------------------

My expected result:
--------------------------------------------
emp ID|name |leave type|quota|date     |day
--------------------------------------------
1     |emp 1|sick      |14   |24-5-2013|2.0
2     |emp 2|sick      |14   |22-5-2013|1.0
3     |emp 3|sick      |14   |null     |null
4     |emp 4|sick      |14   |null     |null
--------------------------------------------
```

I need to show all employee record with sick leave whether have taken or not, and leave table if no taken sick leave, there have no record inside. So i only can get the record that employee have taken sick leave, and i also need total up how many days the employee total taken the leave.

please help, i'm first time post in Stack Overflow.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query="select emp.empId, emp.name, q.leavetype, q.quota, l.date, l.day from employee as emp inner join quota as q on emp.empId = q.empId and q.leavetype = 'sick' inner join leave as l on l.empId = emp.empId and l.leavetype = 'sick'";
```

or

this one will give your desire output

```
select e.id, e.name, q.leavetype, q.quota, le.date, le.day from emp as e inner join quota as q on e.id = q.empId left join emp_leave as le on e.id = le.empId and le.leavetype='sick'
```

Comment: Hi Ranjan thanks for reply, query is correct but the result not i expected, because the employee only show who taken sick leave, but who not taken didn't show NULL, even name also didn't appear.

Comment: You want whether user have taken leave or not it should be display in result

Comment: Yes, i want the user whether have taken sick leave or not also need to display in the result, but now the result is only user which already taken leave will be display, but the user who not taken leave before, it didn't display.

Comment: that's what left [outer] join is for